# Who Uses Real Time Java?

Tags: java, real-time, rtsj, real-time-java

I noticed that [Real Time Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_time_Java) 2.2 was released back in September, seems to have come a long way from when I last looked at it.  However, does anybody know of any real world uses, commercial or academic to date?

http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp

Comment: You may want to specify whether you're looking for users of Sun's specific product (Sun Java Real-Time System) or the Real-Time Specification for Java (RTSJ) in general.

Comment: Well the link there points to the Sun specific version of of real time Java

Comment: **UPDATE** FYI… Progress has been recently made (in year 2015) for real-time Java. See this article, [Little-known real-time standard impacts broad span of Java applications](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2906981/java-app-dev/little-known-real-time-standard-impacts-broad-span-of-java-applications.html).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I offered some publicly-disclosed users of real-time Java in [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/697916/what-languages-are-used-for-real-time-systems-programming/736502#736502); I'll reproduce here:

> The Real-Time Specification for Java
>   now has several commercial-grade
>   implementations:
>
> - <strike>Sun/Oracle's [JavaRTS](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/realtime/index.jsp)</strike> (now [unavailable](http://www.javelinfeedback.com/sun/index.jsp?pi=859927bc085603aa66e68ca214edfb6c&download=x86linux-90days&V=2.2-32bit), it appears Oracle has disbanded the JavaRTS team and made the product unavailable, without communicating publicly about it)
> - IBM's [WebSphere
>     Real-Time](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/realtime/)
> - Aonix [PERC](http://www.aonix.com/perc.html)
> - aicas [JamaicaVM](http://www.aicas.com/sites/jamaica.html)
> - Apogee [Aphelion](http://www.apogee.com/jre.html)
>
> These products span the continuum from
>   compilation to native code (Aonix) to
>   J2ME (aicas, apogee), to full J2SE
>   (Sun, IBM).  Most, if not all, have
>   seen deployments in small numbers of
>   safety- or mission-critical systems,
>   but momentum is building.  Examples
>   include Eglin
>   AFB's space surveillance radar
>   modernization and the US Navy's
>   use of RTSJ in the DDG-1000/Zumwalt
>   destroyer.  Sun also claims
>   deployment in the financial
>   transaction processing domain.
>
> If you are interested in RTSJ, I
>   suggest Peter Dibble's Real-Time Platform Programming, or Professor
>   Wellings' Concurrent
>   and Real-Time Programming in Java.
>
> On a related note, there is also work
>   underway to provide a Safety-Critical
>   profile for the Java programming
>   language, built as a subset of RTSJ. 
>   Also, an expert group has formed to
>   explore a Distributed RTSJ DRTSJ,
>   but the work is stalled.

Not all of the above refers to Sun's JavaRTS or even RTSJ; several vendors have pursued their own proprietary path for real-time Java because they feel the RTSJ doesn't match their customers' needs.

Some additional users I'm aware of now include Army Future Combat Systems and several of the DARPA Urban Challenge contenders.

Answer (score 8):

A version of Korean jet trainer T-50 will have a core application written in Real-time Java.

This Java application provides HUD, MFD diplays and all the core functions of the mission computer.

JamaicaVM from aicas is ported to indigenously developed mission computer.

Flight test is scheduled at the 4th quarter of 2010.

Comment: An update to the T-50 jet trainer running Java... The mission computer running RT Java had a flight test in November 2010. Since then, it is being flown from time to time with other flight test purposes. The RT Java application does all the computing, data interfaces, and graphic displays on the HUD and MFDs.

Answer (score 2):

- [Industrial Robot Control](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1288940.1288955)
- [Embedded and Consumer Devices](http://www.rtjcom.com/main.php?p=show)
- [More Embedded Systems](http://www.apogee.com/home)

Whole lot of other information on various systems in use (you would have to search for who is using those systems) both [here](http://rt.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page) and [here](http://www.osadl.org/RTLWS-2009.rtlws-2009.0.html).

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Very realtime, but not all of the RTSJ standard is Ajile systems, they make hardware realtime java.

I used it on the M101 CROWS fire control computer. It's NOT the bit that failed in the video on youtube.

Comment: I just noted the reference to Ajile and their hardware JVM. Ajile has been out of business for quite a while; Google for details.